# Find first word in a string after a . in javascript

Tags: javascript, split, slice

I am working on a school assignment where we have to highlight the first word after a "." in a text with the press on a button.

As far as i've come I have created a HTML page, the HTML page contains a button and on click it is supposed to highligt the first word after a "." I have discovered that I probably have to use split and or slice.

```
function highligtWord(){

var tekst = document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML;  

for (var i = 0 ;  i < tekst.length; i++) {
    var arr = tekst.split(". ")[i].split(" ")[0] 

    console.log(arr)
    var res = tekst.replace(`${arr}`, "<span style=background-color:yellow>" + `${arr}` + "</span>" );
    document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML += res;     
}
```

So far this does not work as intended as it "highlight" words that aren't after a "." so my question is, what do i do wrong?
And how can I get you "highligt" all words after a "." instead?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider to format this as SO snippet. So others can see your problem clear. This is just a suggestion, but it may improve the quality of your question. Also your code is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd probably be easier to use a regular expression - match `\.` (a literal dot), then match `\S+` - one or more non-space characters. Then replace with the non-space characters surrounded by the highlight span:

```js
const elm = document.getElementById("tekst");
elm.innerHTML = elm.innerHTML.replace(
  /(\. *)(\S+)/,
  '$1<span style=background-color:yellow>$2</span>'
);
```

```html
<div id="tekst">foo bar. baz should be highlighted.</div>
```

If you want to highlight *all* words that follow a `.`, use the global flag instead for the regular expression (use `/g`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! :) I might just be new to JavaScript and regex's but precisely where should I place the /g? 
And once again thanks!

Comment: The same place where all regular expression flags go - after the end of the pattern. eg `/foo/g` is a global pattern for `foo`